# How to use DFA/NFA to prove the language {$0^n 1^$ | x ∈ Σ*, n ≥ 1} is regular?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, pushdown-automata, discrete-mathematics, computational-linguistics

I'm trying to prove the language L = {$0^n 1^$ | x ∈ Σ*, n ≥ 1} is regular, but don't know how to present it in a DFA/NFA.
I'm thinking to have n+1 states in a NFA, with the start state as the accepting state. The NFA reada $0$s to go from q$0$ to q$n+1$, then reading $1$s or $0$s to stay in the q$n+1$, then reading the same number of $1$s to go back to the q$0$. Is this a valid way to prove L is regular?

Comment: There is no limit to $n$: the number of states of a *finite* automaton can't grow with it. (Oops - didn't see one star.)

Comment: Showing an FA with that language might convince even me that $L$ was regular.

Answer (score 3):

Your language consists of all words starting with $0$ and ending with $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution depends on $n$. In this case the $n$ in the formulation of the language is not a constant, but a variable ranging over the positive integers $n\ge 1$. So we need strings of the form $0^n x 1^n$ for any $n\ge 1$, and any $x\in\Sigma^*$.

In general that would not be possible with a FSA, it cannot count and compare the numbers of $0$'s and $1$'s, but this is a trick question. See the answer by Yuval.

Answer (score 1):

Your language is regular and can be rewritten as $$ L = {0\Sigma^*1} 
$$ (start with 0 end with 1)
[image]